# Modifying the Codeigniter calendar to generate unique URLs for each date

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar

I'm trying to create a calendar that will allow a user to click on a date and schedule an appointment or view the appointments scheduled for that date. I was able to do this with a PHP calendar I created from scratch but I now need to do it with Codeigniter's calendar library.

Basically what I want is for the calendar to display each date with a unique URL that can pass the day, month, and year to another view. Is there anyone who has extended or modified the Codeigniter calendar to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the native calendar class:

```
$this->load->library('calendar');

$data = array(
               3  => 'http://example.com/news/article/2006/03/',
               7  => 'http://example.com/news/article/2006/07/',
               13 => 'http://example.com/news/article/2006/13/',
               26 => 'http://example.com/news/article/2006/26/'
             );

echo $this->calendar->generate(2006, 6, $data);
```

Check out the docs for more info: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/calendar.html

Comment: I saw that but it seems pretty cumbersome for what I want to do. I would need an element in the array for every day, and it looks like the month and/or year must be hard coded in? I ended up doing this and then loading it with the calendar: `$template['template'] = '{cal_cell_no_content}<div class="day_num"><a href="/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/{day}">{day}</a></div>{/cal_cell_no_content}';`

Comment: makes sense. glad to hear you found a solution.